# Importing the OpenCamera project into Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, open-source

I am using the Open Camera app and just wanted to do some small changes to the file naming after pictures are taken. I downloaded the source code from https://github.com/kush-mish/Open-camera and installed Android Studio 2022.2. I imported the project but I can't find out how I need to set it up (build and run configurations etc) such that I can run the emulator or see why it fails. I had problems with modules and skd, problems with synching the gradle. Sometimes the build finishes but I still can't run it.  I tried importing the project in IntelliJ too. When I do that I manage to build the project but when i run the emulator (everything starts without errors) it only shows the common android interface - I don't see the Open Camera App as installed app. I know a bit about the file structure of those projects and maybe made a button or two work in java projects but I normally don't code Android Apps or use Android studio.
Can someone give me a bit of a stepbystep what i need to do or consider setting this project up?
Or another way, how i could simply edit and emulate this source code a bit?

All the best ;)
(PS: sry, please tell me if you need more information, I'm not sure what all i need to provide right now)